# Code slider has spacing in bottom which i can not get rid off

Tags: html, css

I have this html code which runs fine, but now I have the green background but somehow there is white spacing underneath the black border and I don't know how to get rid of that. Any ideas?

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #A3E6BD;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.marquee {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'OPTIImprovNewWideNine';
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}

.marquee p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="marquee">
    <p>
      @PEACHIENL - #PEACHIENL - @PEACHIENL - # PEACHIENL -
    </p>
    <p>
      @PEACHIENL - #PEACHIENL - @PEACHIENL - # PEACHIENL -
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. The code you've posted so far doesn't show us the problem. I put your code into an executable snippet, and you can update it as needed.

Comment: Yes understand, thank you for that!

Comment: Try with adding `margin-bottom : -11px` negative values to parent div named `wrapper`

Comment: Thank you dinesh i tried but was to much then i did -2px !important; and now works thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #A3E6BD;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: -2px !important;
}

.marquee {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'OPTIImprovNewWideNine';
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}

.marquee p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="marquee">
    <p>
      @PEACHIENL - #PEACHIENL - @PEACHIENL - # PEACHIENL -
    </p>
    <p>
      @PEACHIENL - #PEACHIENL - @PEACHIENL - # PEACHIENL -
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```